# .NET Attribute Class Plugging

Tags: .net, custom-attributes

Is there any way to write a custom class which extends .NET Attribute class so that I can apply that class on a method and .NET Framework calls my class constructor before executing that method. Here is the example

```
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMethod();
    }

    [TestAttribute()]
    public static void TestMethod()
    {

    }

}
```

I want when TestMethod is called, framework will execute TestAttribute() constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular .NET attributes don't cause magic invocation, except for a very limited set of system attributes (security etc). The rest are applied *only* by inspection through reflection, which has to be done explicitly.

You might look at PostSharp (now renamed into a [commercial product](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)).

Comment: Another option (ASP.NET MVC only) is creating a subclass of `ActionFilterAttribute`. See an example [here](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/03/21/ActionFilterAttributeExamplesASPNETMVCFrameworkPreview2.aspx).

Comment: @rsenna that is a very specific example that is still ultimately invoked via reflection.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: 1) That's why I added it as a comment, not as a response. 2) It gets the job done (the OP wants to add runtime behavior to a method, I don't think he/she cares about implementation details). 3) I gave you a +1, so don't complain! ;-)

Comment: I use .NET Framework 3.5 (Web forms). Can I use System.Web.Mvc assemblies without any problem? I do not find these assemblies on my machine. Will it impact the performance significantly if it uses reflection?

Comment: @kumar: no, I don't think it is a good idea to use `ActionFilterAttribute` in WebForms - it is a ASP.NET MVC only approach. You should try PostSharp, or some other AOP library.

Comment: Anyway, I will live with calling my attribute class explicitly from inside  the function rather than framework to call it automatically. I was under the impression that I can write my custom attribute class like PrincipalPermission class. I do not want to use any third party solution.

Comment: After digging further I found a way to extend CodeAccessSecurityAttribute class. Is there any problem in doing so? Please advise?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so - Attributes are only read by things reflecting over the code, they aren't called during normal execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but not as is.

You can do that by using Aspect Oriented Programming.  PostSharp is a framework that allows you to do that; it allows you to 'weave' aspects into the code at compile time.

[Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download)

```
[Serializable]
public class TestAttribute : OnMethodInvocationAspect
{
   public override void OnInvocation()
   {
       Console.WriteLine ("TestAttribute called");
       base.OnInvocation();
   }
}
```